# How do you get the results from a UIDatePicker upon change?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios13

My app broke when iOS 13 was released and I can't figure out how to fix it (Yes, yes, I know iOS 13 has been out for a while, I'm just getting around to looking into this).

I have a UIDatePicker which is being used as a setting for a time that the user wants to trigger a notification. It's in HH:MM format derived via the Date > Custom in the Inspector. All I need to do is get whatever the user has changed the time to and store it in variables: One for Hour and another for Minutes. These variables will then be used to update the UserDefaults upon clicking the Save button.

This is what I have now, which used to work pre-iOS 13:

```
    @IBAction func startDayPickerControl(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // sets the hour and min vars to whatever was changed on the startDayPicker

        hour = sender.hour
        min = sender.minute

        print("Start day set to \(hour):\(min)")
    }
```

It's hooked up to the swift file as follows:
[image]

And then my Save button would do this:

```
@IBAction func saveSettingsButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
       
        appUserSettings.set(hour, forKey: "hour")
        appUserSettings.set(min, forKey: "min")

        print("saveSettingsButton tapped")
    }
```

I can't figure out why the date picker isn't outputting the data upon change. All I get in the `print("Start day set to \(hour):\(min)")` is "Start day set to 0:0"

I tried a test project in case something got messed up with my existing one during Swift version conversions. This is what I have and I'm getting the same 0:0 print result:

`class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var hour = 8
var min = 30

@IBOutlet var CurrentSetTime: UILabel!

@IBAction func TimePicker(_ sender: Any) {
    // sets the hour and min vars to whatever was changed on the startDayPIcker
    // Xcode forced these changes from my above code here, but didn't on my original project
    hour = (sender as AnyObject).hour 
    min = (sender as AnyObject).minute
    
    CurrentSetTime.text = "\(hour):\(min)"
    print("Start day set to \(hour):\(min)")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

}`

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

I think there may be an issue in the way you are handling the type and fields of of sender (which I believe changed in your recent question edits, AnyObject vs. Any etc.)

Try this:

```
@IBAction func TimePicker(_ sender: Any) {
    if let picker = sender as? UIDatePicker {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let tempHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: picker.date)
        let tempMinute = calendar.component(.minute, from: picker.date)

        Swift.print("hour: \(tempHour) minute: \(tempMinute)")
        hour = tempHour
        minute = tempMinute
    }
}
```

You can get rid of the temp variables once it's working but I think it will help to step through and explicitly see what your types are and what properties of the sender you are accessing.

---

**Original answer:**

How is your picker hooked up to the @IBAction in your .xib?

I'm not sure the correct way in earlier system versions but it should work if you hook up the **Value Changed** connection to the controller @IBAction, as pictured:

[image: screenshot of UIDatePicker and Value Changed connection]

Comment: It's hooked up to the correct @IBAction control.

`@IBAction func startDayPicker(_ sender: AnyObject)`

Comment: When I try this setup in a current (Xcode 11, iOS 13) project, it works fine - the change of values calls the @IBAction function and the hour and min values are obtained from the sender.

Comment: I can't figure out why my print outputs are like this then `Start day set to 0:0`

Comment: How are your hour and min members defined? Try setting local variables to help debug, e.g. let tempHour = sender.hour, let tempMin = sender.min, and see what those are in the debugger. They should be optionals, Int?, with the correct values.

Comment: `var hour = 8
    var min = 30
    @IBOutlet var CurrentSetTime: UILabel!
    @IBAction func TimePicker(_ sender: Any) {
        // sets the hour and min vars to whatever was changed on the startDayPIcker
        hour = (sender as AnyObject).hour
        min = (sender as AnyObject).minute
        CurrentSetTime.text = "\(hour):\(min)"
        print("Start day set to \(hour):\(min)")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }`

Comment: well that's ugly and hard to read... I'll move it up to the description

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I don't understand why my previous version worked though consider how vastly different it was from yours? Regardless, thank you very much!